# UIGestureRecognizer type catch in gestureRecognizerShouldBegin

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to catch the type of `UIGestureRecognizer`.
Am I allowed to do it this way?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Gesture should begin");
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UIRotationGestureRecognizer class]])
        NSLog(@"rotate");
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]])
        NSLog(@"pinch");
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
        NSLog(@"tap");
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
        NSLog(@"pan");
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        NSLog(@"long");
    if ([gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]])
        NSLog(@"swipe");
    return NO;
}
```

I have a long touch gesture in table view cell.
If I press the cell I receive a log:

```
-[FileObjectView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] [Line 45] Gesture should begin
-[FileObjectView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] [Line 55] long
```

And I want it to work this way.

But sometimes while I scroll my table view I receive a log:

```
-[FileObjectView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] [Line 45] Gesture should begin
```

It makes me think that I'm not aware of some type of gesture.

Can anybode explain the situation?

Comment: Ya , and it worked for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to check the class name this way:

```
NSLog(@"%@",gestureRecognizer.class);
```

Class name is: `UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`

I have checked this issue a lot of times on differen iOS versions.

This thing happens only on iOS 6. One more iOS 6 bug?!